# Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NotificationsComponent

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, testing

Full Error when run `ng test`:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NotificationsComponent
>
> AuthService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NotificationsComponent AuthService]:
>
> NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthService!
>
> Expected undefined to be truthy.
>
> Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
>
> at stack (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2176:17)
>
> at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2146:14)
>
> at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:766:18)
>
> at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:444:34)
>
> at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:710:21)
>
> at Expectation.toBeTruthy (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2099:12)
>
> at Object. (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/../webTest/src/app/components/notifications/notifications.component.spec.ts:97:23)
>
> at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/C:/../webTest/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
>
> at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/../webTest/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
>
> at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/../webTest/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)

my code service:

```
describe('Component: Auth', () => {


    let component: AuthService;

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthService>;


    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            declarations: [AuthService]

        })

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthService);

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

    });

});
```

Can you ask me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Use it like below :

Services should be in `providers` array.

```
describe('Component: Auth', () => {
let component: AuthService;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [],
        providers: [AuthService] // **Like this.**
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate service: `let service = new AuthService();`, there is no need to call "createComponent" and such.

https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests